# Пользовательская имплементация IEnumerator<T>.Current. Определение поведения Current до вызова MoveNext

Tags: c#

Допустим Current вызывается до MoveNext, что нужно сделать в этом случае? Какое должно быть поведение?  Выбросить исключение? Или вернуть значение по умолчанию? В MSDN просто говорится, что Current должен/может быть неопределённым, но что будет хорошей практикой? Понятно, вопрос дискуссионный, но интересно мнение людей.

```
public struct Enumerator : IEnumerator<T>
{
    // просто для примера: флаг, что MoveNext не был вызван, и, соответствено, Current не валиден
    bool readyToWork;

    // вариант 1
    public T Current
    {
        get
        {
            if (readyToWork) return validCurrentValue;
            else throw new SomeException("Call MoveNext first!");
        }
    }

    // вариант 2
    public T Current
    {
        get
        {
            if (readyToWork) return validCurrentValue;
            else return default;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`default` же, посмотрите как это на классических коллекциях работает. Я бы не придумывал велосипед.

С другой стороны, любому разработчику понятно, что для начала перечисления нужно вызвать `MoveNext`. Поэтому при верной реализации итератора, материализующего перечисление, совершенно неважно что оно будет возвращать.